# tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Op type not registered 'I mageProjectiveTransform'

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to rotate the image randomly at the image preprocessing. But I got an error when running the code`image=tf.contrib.image.rotate(image, rotate_angle)`.

And it returns`tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Op type not registered 'ImageProjectiveTransform'`

How could I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and it is apparently a problem in tensorflow.

There is an open issue at the tensorflow repository (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9672). Hopefully it will be solved soon!